# How do I specify a generic type where one of the types is not needed?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a generic datatype where one of the types is not needed (edge weights in a graph). I've been thinking to use the never type for this, which would look something like this:

```
#![feature(never_type)]

struct Foo<T> {
    bar: T
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn foo(&mut self, bar: T) {
        self.bar = bar;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo: Foo<!> = Foo { bar: "nada" };
    foo.foo("nada");
}
```

This obviously results in a type-mismatch for the `"nada"` placeholders, but just typing nothing will cause other errors. Is `!` the right type to use here, and if so, what's the correct syntax?

I've gotten it to work using `()` instead of `!`, but I'm a bit unsure as to whether that's the proper choice of type. I believe in terms of efficiency it should make no difference, as `()` has no memory footprint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`()` is the right choice.  It is a type with a single value (also named `()`), so it has a value, but contains no information.

`!` doesn't have any value, so if you put it in a struct the struct type doesn't have a value either and is basically unusable.

Comment: This answer is correct, but there *are* times where you'd want to use `!` as a type. Further reading: [RFC 1216](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1216-bang-type.md) and the corresponding [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35121).

Comment: Note I didn't say `!` is unusable, only the struct isn't very useful (though it could be used to signal that code is never executed like `!` itself). I actually do like RFC 1216.